# Is it possible to connect two phones to the same bluetooth device at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth

We've got bluetooth device that returns some data and program on Android market that connects to this device, grabs this data and prints it. We wrote our on program which do the same thing. We would like to test it by running this progs at the same time and comparing data.

1. Is it possible to connect two different phones to the same bluetooth device at the same time?
2. Is it possible to grab data from device (by bluetooth) by two different programs on the same device at the same time?

Comment: BT specifies support for 7 parallel incoming connections for the "server" device, i.e. the device which _accepts_ the connections. It also specifies a parallel outgoing connection. However, that's only what a full-flavoured radio needs to be able to do -- there's no obligation for the software to support it as well -- think BT headsets, for example -- pretty wide scope from a single paired device to several with fade-over features. In other words, your question cannot be answered on this general level.

Comment: Do you mean that it depends on device which I'm going to connect? How can I check it (I've tried to connect two phones - first one is ok, second - failure)? Does API has special params to support such situation? Still don't have answer for second question

Comment: You did not provide any information on the device you want to connect to. Is it third party, is it closed source, which documentation do you have, etc. So from where I stand, I have no clear picture of the situation you're in. But yes, it solely depends on the capabilities of the device you try to connect to. There's nothing you can do on the phones to help this situation. The other device either supports parallel connections, or it doesn't.